# Comparison of various I/O function in C based on K&R

Tags: c

After reading K&R, it seems there are lot of I/O functions in C besides the familiar ones like printf, scanf, getchar, etc. Also, there some nuances for some of them like whether the '\n' characters is stored or not, EOF or NULL is return on error, default input stream (stdin/keyboard), etc. Here is list of I/P functions that I have been able to come up with:

I/P Functions:
    **scanf
    fscanf
    getchar
    fgetc
    getc
    gets**

When I read their descriptions individually I seem to get it, but if I have to choose one over another I get confuse and everything gets jumbled up in my mind, if you know what I mean. Can anyone clearly summarize when to use which function and pros and cons of choosing one over another (getchar vs getc vs scanf)?

Bonus Point: Where does the K&R's getline function fits in in the above scenario?

Comment: Can you give an example of task which makes a decision between these functions difficult?

Answer (score 3):

The difference between Input and Output is obvious in the OP, so let's focus in the other ones.

**Difference 1**: Some functions take a `FILE*`, some will assume one: `stdint` for Input, `stdout` for output). If you are goint to use the `stdin/stdout` files, just use the simpler ones:

- Take `FILE*`: `fprintf`, `fscanf`, `fgetc`, `fgets`, `fputc`, `fputs`.
- Do not take `FILE*`: `printf`, `scanf`, `getchar`, `gets`, `putchar`, `puts`.

Note the pattern? Functions that start with `f` have the `FILE*`... exceptions are `putc` and `getc`, that are equivalent to their `f*` counterparts. Just don't use them... they are weird.

**Difference 2**: Some functions format the arguments, some take a single char, some take a string. That's easy to see, I'm too lazy to enumerate them again. Use whatever fits you best.

**Difference 3**: Some functions should not be used at all. IMO they are `getc`, `putc`, `gets`, `puts`. They are weird, weird, impossible to use right, and weird, respectively.

**Difference 4**: Return value. All functions return `int` with the read/written character  (or `EOF` on error) except:

- `fgets` and `gets` that return the same pointer that they take as argument (or `NULL` if error). That was thought to be handy to save lines of code: `memcpy(buffer, fgets(buffer2, 100, file));`. But since you should be checking the error before using the pointer, the actual return value is mostly useless except for comparing it to `NULL.`
- `*printf` returns the number of bytes written.
- `*scanf` returns the number of input items read.

Well, it is not a table, but IHTH.

Comment: "... or NULL if error" oversimplifies.  On an input error, they do return `NULL`.  On end-of-file, not really an _error_, they also return `NULL`.